# How to set the text of the comboBox items with a converter?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a converter that binds to a collection which elements are of type MyType. I would like to set the text that it is sound withd a converter. So to start with a quick test, I am trying first to set the text of all elements with the text "Hello".

I am trying to use this code:

```
<ComboBox
          DisplayMemberPath="MyProperty"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          ItemsSource="{MyViewModelCollection}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Text" Value="Hello"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

However, it is shown the value of the property set in DisplayMemeberPath.

So for the first step I would like to know how to set to all items the text "Hello" but my idea it is to use a converter that takes the comboBoxItem, and according to some checks, returns the text that I want to show.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of DisplayMemberPath, set the `ItemTemplate` property to an appropriate DataTemplate with a TextBlock:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyViewModelCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty,
                              Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: As a note, SelectedItem binds TwoWay by default.